# Finding the AVG

Tags: sql

I'm working on a small project for my portfolio and relatively new to SQL, came across an unguided project with this question.

Over the course of the year in Canada, with the date of 2022-01-01 , how many cities had an average city temperature of less than 0 degrees? This is what I have:

```
SELECT COUNT(temp) 
FROM table
WHERE date = '2022-01-01'
HAVING AVG(temp) < 0
```

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Please add sample data for your table.

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only one tag for the database product you are really using.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: 'This returns 0 results which shouldn't be the case given the dataset.' - why not given there is no grouping happening

Comment: If you want to use a city's average temperature in the filter, you Must `GROUP BY` the city column.

Comment: Can you really get a day range between -40 and +40? Tough place Canada.

Comment: "over the course of a year" / "with date 2022-01-01" - something doesn't quite match

Answer (score 1):

Deconstructing your question:

1. select only valid temps and date
2. group by city
3. select city and avg
4. consider only grouped values below 0

```
    select city, avg(temp)
     where temp between -40 and 40
       and date = '2022-01-01'
     group by city
    having avg(temp) < 0
```

Comment: Put in a sub query and in main query count number of cities?

Comment: @P.Salmon yes that should get you the count

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT city,COUNT(temp) 
FROM table
WHERE date = '2022-01-01'
group by city
HAVING AVG(temp) < 0
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

//--sub query-- filtered with average temperature<0 & date 2022-01-01
//--main query-- count all of sub query result

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT city, AVG(temp)
      FROM table 
      WHERE DATE = '2022-01-01'
      GROUP BY city
      HAVING AVG(temp)<0;) ;
```